# getting first part of a string that has two parts

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, cut

I have a string that has two parts (path and owner) both separated by a space.

This is the input file input.txt

```
/dir1/dir2/file1 @owner1
/dir1/dir2/foo\ bar @owner2
```

I want to extract all the paths to a separate output file - output.txt
I cannot use space as delimiter since paths can also have filenames with space and delimiter in them

```
/dir1/dir2/file1
/dir1/dir2/foo\ bar
```

Comment: I tried to use       cut -d" " -f1     but this would get me the full paths as some of the paths are separated by space too

Comment: @kushanky, Thank you for letting us know your efforts,please do add them in your question as comments are not meant to write codes. Please edit your post with same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here could be a different way of doing it with `rev` + GNU `grep`:

```
rev file | grep -oP '.*@ \K.*' | rev
```

***OR***

```
rev file | grep -oP '.*@\s+\K.*' | rev
```

---

With original simple solution go with:

```
awk -F' @' '{print $1}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming spaces that shouldn't be parsed as delimiters are escaped by a backslash as in your sample, you could use the following regex :

```
^(\\ |[^ ])*
```

For instance with `grep` :

```
grep -oE '^(\\ |[^ ])*'
```

The regex matches from the start of the line any number of either a backslash followed by a space or any other character than a space and will stop at the first occurence of a space that isn't preceded by a backslash.

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/9FJJjt).

Answer (score 1):

I would trim the ending part with sed.

`sed 's/ [^ ]*$//' /path/to/file`

This will match from the end of the line:

- (blank) matches the space character
- `[^ ]*` matches the longest string that contains no spaces, i.e. `@owner1`
- `$` matches the end of the line

And they will be replaced by nothing, which will act as if you deleted the matched string.

Answer (score 1):

A one-line would do it:

```sh
while read p _; do printf '%q\n' "$p"; done <input.txt >output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put them in an array and process

```
mapfile test < input.txt; test=("${test[@]% *}")
echo "${test[@]}"
echo "${test[0]}"
echo "${test[1]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with simple awk

```
awk ' { $NF=""; print } '
```

Try it here https://ideone.com/W8J1ZO